# What were the advantages of sheepfolds?

Tags: middle-ages

In the British Isles (and other regions of the world) drywall pens were built for sheep. In England they were called sheepfolds.

What the the advantages of this format over others in common use at the time?

For example as a shelter in a pasture to use for inclement weather? Or a convenient place to put all the sheeps while shearing? I don't know a lot about modern or historical livestock management to get more specific so I like to get an understanding of how they were used in medieval times.

**ANSWER**
Thanks to Red Sonja, I did a search and found [numerous allusion](https://www.google.com/search?q=medieval%20sheepfold%20protection%20at%20night&safe=off&rlz=1C1GIWA_enUS663US663&ei=T8emWYCAAsXTjwSUwqjQBg&start=10&sa=N&biw=1107&bih=721) to the historical use of a sheepfold as a means of protecting a herd of sheep during the night from thieves and animals. Something that not stated in Wikipedia or various dictionaries. Or that you get by typing in just sheep fold back in 2014.

This is [the clearest article](http://www.bible-history.com/sketches/ancient/sheep-fold.html) I found.

Comment: This is a trivial question. Answer found in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pen_(enclosure))

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace all the wikipedia article tells me is that it is a holding pen for livestock. It doesn't tell what holding pens were used for as part of managing livestock. There are lot of reasons that you need to pen up animals.  That part isn't clear.

Comment: Ahh - then I would respectfully suggest that those questions are not historical in nature, but agricultural. Based on my limited knowledge, there are multiple reasons to confine livestock (quarantine, feeding, breeding, shearing, killing, etc.); generally any task that is easier if you don't have to start by *catching* the livestock.  I suspect the uses of a sheepfold are manifold.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I don't care about the use of pens modern agriculture but rather how it was used in the middle ages, hence it is a historical question.

Comment: @RSConley it may be, but I wouldn't be sure. If it's too technical, it belongs to that specific field anyway.

Comment: @RSConley: You should edit the question to link to the Wikipedia article so people know that you have gotten "that far." My other changes regarded the historical "functionality" of the sheepfold.

Comment: Not just the middle ages. A sheepfold is a place to gather all your sheep in one place. Obviously there are many reasons to do this. The main one being, many years ago, to keep them safe at night, to protect them from raptors and robbers. Now this is no longer a problem in e.g. England, you still see them because nobody pulled them down. You never know, after all. They want to reintroduce wolves.

Comment: @RedSonja thanks that was the kind of answer I was looking for. After incorporating that into my goggle search I found numerous references to that use. Thanks.